# MySQL Proxy step by step configuration

Tags: mysql, windows, proxy, lua, load-balancing

I have an apache web server in my local network (local ip 192.168.0.100). There is a web-site which uses a MySQL database. I added one more slave server (local ip 192.168.0.101) and configured database replication. Now, I want to add a Proxy server for load balancing (at least to test how it works). So, I installed MySQL Proxy on another machine (local ip 192.168.0.102), I created a service in this way

```
C:\> sc create "Proxy" DisplayName= "MySQL Proxy" start= "auto" binPath="C:\mysql-proxy\bin\mysql-proxy-svc.exe --defaults-file= C:mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy.cnf"
```

In coonfiguration file, which is `mysql-proxy.cnf` I have put these lines:

```
[mysql-proxy]
daemon = true
log-file = "C:\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy.log"
log-level = debug
proxy-address = 192.168.0.102:4040
proxy-backend-addresses = 192.168.0.100:3306,192.168.0.101:3306
```

In coomand line I ran

```
net start proxy
```

And I see, that it is running without errors. But now I'm stuck and do not know what to do next. In some guides they suggest running this query:

```
mysql> select * from proxy_connections;
```

But where to run, how to run - no one says it. If I just run it on my master server, I obviously get an error "No database selected". Other user guides almost from the very start discuss lua scripting. But I do not need that, at least now. What I want is to simply check load balancing. A simple test case would be to execute a query to the database, and to see, how proxy works. Besides, guys, I see that mysql proxy `share` folder contains a lot of lua scripts. I see `ro-balance` for example. `Lib` directory contains also `balance.lua`. I guess, load balancing will be easier with these scripts -  probably I will have to just specify read and write servers. So, if you have already gone through all these steps - to get just the simplest load balancing work, please, share your experience.

Answer (score 3):

Start MySQL proxy in this way:

```
C:\MySQL_proxy\> mysql-proxy.exe --proxy-backend-addresses=<MySQLserver host/IP>:mysql server port --proxy-address=<proxy host>:<proxy port>
```

You can test by using Mysql command line tool or any other MySQL client and see whether it is connecting to MySQL proxy or not.

```
mysql -uroot -p -hmysql_proxy-host-name -Pmysql-proxy-port
```

Comment: When I do C:\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy.exe... I get an error: "unknown option: 192.168.0.100:3306".

Comment: mysql -uroot -p -h192.168.0.102 -P4040 results in an error: Can't connect to MySQL server. The catch is there is no mysql installed on the proxy, but just mysql proxy. Besides, I think I could make an error in the syntax of "mysql -uroot -p -hmysql_proxy-host-name -Pmysql-proxy-port".

Comment: If you are using MySQL proxy version 0.81 alpha then syntax is:

mysql-proxy --proxy-backend-addresses=<mysql host>:3306 --proxy-address=<proxy host>:<proxy port> --admin-username=root --admin-password=root

make sure that proxy is started successfully then only try to connect using MySQL commandline

Comment: admin-username is your MySQL server username and admin-password is password associated with MySQL user

Comment: Now I get an error "Unknown option: --admin-username=root". As for the version I use the last release - 0.8.3.

Comment: hmm .. make sure that you typed --proxy-backend-addresses and proxy-address option correctly and remove --admin options. 

Now I do not have setup otherwise I could have helped you in syntax. If still there is a problem you can report in bugs.mysql.com under proxy section

Comment: Now I see it started. I used this line "mysql-proxy ----proxy-backend-addresses=192.168.0.100:3306 --proxy-address:192.168.0.102:4040". By the way, why should I start it in this way and not to use a default file with settings? And can you, please, clarify the syntax for "mysql -uroot -p -hmysql_proxy-host-name -Pmysql-proxy-port".

Comment: http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-proxy-en.pdf this has lot of information about proxy, this will be helpful.

Comment: Official documentation is rather vague. For example, it says to run "mysql --host=localhost --port=4040" to connect to MySQL server. But I do not understand what host should actually be - either 192.168.0.102 (IP of the proxy server) OR 192.168.0.100 (IP of the master server). And by the way, as for `select * from proxy_connections` which should return a result set, as in user guides, how can I execute this query? On the master-server, but what database should be specified? Any?